# Hacking attempt, process running under 'apache' user

Tags: apache, security, curl, centos

Our system blocked an hacking attempt coming from a local process running under the **apache** system user.

```
Process not allowed.

{
"USER": "apache 16",
"PID": "617",
"%CPU": "0.0",
"%MEM": "0.0 80",
"VSZ": "556 3",
"RSS": "904",
"TTY": "?",
"STAT": "S",
"TIME": "0:00",
"COMMAND": "curl -v -u -d yyyy http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/"
}
```

How could the apache user run curl?

From the /etc/passwd file:

```
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin
```

Shouldn't this block **apache** from running any command?

We are running CentOS release 6.7 (Final) with SELinux enforced.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not trying to solve a specific programming problem.

Comment: Maybe it could be moved to unix.stackexchange? Sorry about that..

Comment: I don't know whether it is suited on there. I suggest to read their rules: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) / [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and check out the current questions and answers on there.

Answer (score 1):

/sbin/nologin just means you cannot get a shell on login. It is to prevent direct shell access.
You could still run scripts using that same user having "nologin" as,

> su -s "/bin/sh cat /etc/passwd" apache

By the log you provided I suggest to audit the server and web application's on the server.
As this could be a Remote Code Execution (RCE) vulnerability , or the hacker could have already exploited some other vulnerability and uploaded [web shell](https://github.com/tennc/webshell) in some web application, and is trying to get more privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You do not require a shell to run commands.
If a vulnerability exists within apache itself or within the code apache executes then an attacker can run commands as the apache user.

For example, assume Apache executes the following code:

```
<?
    passthru($_GET["cmd"]);
?>
```

Any command sent through the **cmd** parameter would be executed by the apache user.
If the apache user couldn't run any command then you couldn't run the Apache server or execute any script files through it.